# SECOND SIM DOES'NT SEND SMS (CORDOVA-PLUGIN-SMS)

Tags: cordova, sms

Im using cordova to build my cross-platform app.
The problem is that i can´t use the second SIM to send SMS, and even if there is only 1 SIM on the second slot it return error on send.
sms working
long sms working
just need a way to send the sms if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate a default SIM card for SMS.